# I want to display the list of attachments from a single textview using a list. But I'm able to display only one object

Tags: android, listview

I'm making an app where I want to display I want to display all the attachments. But can view only one attachment. Below is the function along with the XML :

```
//this is the function that displays attachments:    
public void showAttachments(List<Attachment> attachments) {
    mAttachmentsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    for (Attachment attachment : attachments) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.attachment_item_layout,   mAttachmentsLayout, true); 
        view.setTag(attachment);

        //inflating the layout xml file
        TextView attachmentTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.attachment_title); 
        String title = attachment.getFileName();
        //getFileName() returns the name of the attachment

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
            title = attachment.getFileName();
        }

        //assigning title to textview:
        attachmentTitle.setText(title);

        //want to display all attachments
        //not just one

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mBasePermissionPresenter.onClickAttachment((Attachment)v.getTag());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Attachments container size increases but only one attachment name is shown

This is the corresponding XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/attachmentHeading"
            android:padding='@dimen/posting_details_attachment_item_padding'
            android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:id="@+id/attachment_title"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

I know the solution is really easy but please help out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to only single attachment because you are inflating the same view every time in this fragment of code:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.attachment_item_layout,   mAttachmentsLayout, true);
```

You can get your desired result in two ways:

- Create different layout.xml for every Image (This will be a lot of work)
- or you can add image at run time

I would go with the second option. Do not set your image in the **xml** file instead add the image at runtime. The code goes as follows:

```
ImageView imView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(Your_Image_View_ID_here);
imView.setImageResource(Your_Resource_File_ID_Here);
```

And change the **Resource_Id** as the loop increments. 
Have fun :)

Comment: Played around with your suggestion and now it's working. Cheers mate :)